# Inbox doesn't highlight in app with notifications disabled

Tags: bug, notifications, ios-app

I've disabled push notifications for the app.

The inbox doesn't show any kind of notification indicator like on the site. If I don't open the inbox myself, there are no visual alerts that there is something new in the inbox.

[image]

With notifications enabled, the indicator works.

Comment: So you don't see the red number over the inbox icon if notifications are disabled?

Comment: I didn't got any red number.

Comment: Hmm. I've gone ahead and disabled notifications. Can you send me another message?

Comment: Ok. I've tested it right now, with your previous comment. I had no red number.

Comment: Confirmed. No inbox icon with notifications disabled. There's no reason that should be the case. Definitely a bug